# Не добавляется ссылка на тестируемый проект

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2017

Не могу добавить ссылку на проект в проекте с тестами, кто нибудь знает как это решить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, проект модульных тестов сделан на .NET Core. Поэтому и не может добавить ссылку на нативный проект.

Comment: Тестовые проекты для C++ пишутся как обычный проект.